# comparing two tables and filter based on identity

Tags: perl

I am having a little trouble writing a script that iterates through two different tables and filters lines based on identity. I am just realizing that this might exceed my knowledge on perl by far, so I hope I can get some handy tips from you guys!

I have two tab separated tables that look like this:

alleles.txt:

```
chr     pse.bp  bp      nalleles        maf     acc-1   acc-2   acc-3   acc-4    acc-5   acc-6    acc-7    acc-8   acc-9    acc-10    acc11    acc12    acc13 acc14    acc15
1       11      11      2       18      T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       C       T
1       18      18      2       18      T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       T       C       T
1       22      21.5    3       16      0       0       0       T       0       0       0       0       0       0       T       TCCTAAAT        0       0       0
```

hmp.txt:

```
rs#     alleles chrom   pos     strand  assembly#       center  protLSID        assayLSID       panelLSID       QCcode  M.10        M.101       M.103
NA      NA      1       10971981        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      2       1       2
NA      NA      1       11716572        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      1       1       1
```

I want to write a script to process this data this way:

I need the information from alleles.txt but I don't need every line. I want the program to take the first line of alleles.txt, and if it finds a line in hmp.txt in which the first column of alleles.txt matches the third column of hmp.txt, and the third column of alleles.txt matches the fourth column of hmp.txt, it should write this line into a new file. This I want to do for every single line in allels.txt.
I tried to do this with a nested while loop, here is the code that I have tried to get running so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# maghap.pl
# converts pre-processed alleles layout into TASSEL-readable hapmap format.
# type ./maghap.pl hmp.txt alleles.txt to use this program.
use strict;#use warnings;

die "usage: ./maghap.pl RSB.lars.hmp.txt alleles.txt\n" unless (@ARGV == 2);
#open(my $hapmap, "<", "$ARGV[0]") or die "ERROR loading $ARGV[0]\n";
open(my $alleles, "<", "$ARGV[1]") or die "ERROR loading $ARGV[1]\n";
open(my $out, ">", "$ARGV[1].realsnps") or die "ERROR creating $ARGV[1].realsnps\n";

while (my $allelesline = <$alleles>) {
  #chomp;
  my @alleles_columns = split (/\t/, $allelesline);
  #print $out "@alleles_columns";
  #my $hit = 0;
  open(my $hapmap, "<", "$ARGV[0]") or die "ERROR loading $ARGV[0]\n";
  while (my $hapmapline = <$hapmap>) {
  #chomp;
    my @hapmap_columns = split(/\t/, $hapmapline);
    #print $out "@hapmap_columns";
    if ($alleles_columns[0] == $hapmap_columns[2]) {
      if ($alleles_columns[2] == $hapmap_columns[3]) {
        print $out "@alleles_columns";
        #print $out "@hapmap_columns";
        #$hit = 1;
        last;
      }
    }
  #print $out "@alleles_columns" if $hit;
  }
  close $hapmap;
}
#close $hapmap;
close $alleles;
close $out;
```

As you can see by all the commented lines, I tried out a lot of things, but it seems I am stuck now...
So far the program is at least running but for some reason it cannot find any match (there are matches, I checked). If I turn off the second if-condition (only looking for things matching in the first if-condition), it does find a lot of matches; however if I turn off the first condition (only looking for things matching the second), it does not find anything.
I should probably also mention that both files contain around 800.000 lines, so looping over the one files for every single line might not be a good option; however, I cannot think of a better one! I think this might be easier using hashes, but I cannot think of a smart way to compile this into hashes. If you guys have any tips for me how I can make this work, I would be so happy!

thanks a lot in advance!

Prawn

Comment: Are the numbers in the relevant columns always ascending?

Comment: yes, all 4 relevant columns are ascending in numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the example data you gave. Run as `script.pl alleles.txt hmp.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $AL,  '<', shift or die $!;
open my $HMP, '<', shift or die $!;

# Skip headers
<$AL>;
<$HMP>;

my ($chr_h, $pos_h) = (-1, -1);
while (<$AL>) {
    my ($chr_a, $pos_a) = (split /\t/)[0, 2];
    while ($chr_h < $chr_a and $pos_h < $pos_a) {
        ($chr_h, $pos_h) = (split /\t/, <$HMP>)[2, 3];
    }
    if ($chr_h == $chr_a and $pos_h == $pos_a) {
        print;
       ($chr_h, $pos_h) = (-1, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! this is by far better than what I have compiled! :) however, it only gives me back one line, and I know for sure that there should be more hits. is it possible that it stops after iterating through the first outer loop? (I read somewhere that perl always reads a file from the top to the bottom, so if you want to read through a file for every loop round, you would have to open and close it at the beginning and end of the loop over and over. IDK if this is true)

Comment: @Prawn: If all the numbers are ascending, it shouldn't matter. Can you post the smallest part of your input files that replicates the problem?

Comment: @Prawn: You were right, you need to reset the hmp values, but not always - only after a line is printed. Fixed.

Comment: @chroroba awesome, this works perfectly! if you have the time, could you maybe elaborate a little bit on how the script works? especially in the initiation of the inner while loop, i'm not quite sure if i'm getting what's happening there.

Comment: @Prawn: The inner loop reads the next line from the hmp file, but only if it is needed, i.e. if the relevant numbers are less than those read from the allleles file. So, you read 1 line from alleles, read lines from hmp until the numbers are too large, then read another line from alleles, and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to bother you again, but I just saw that there is an error occuring when you run the script: Use of uninitialized value $pos_h in numeric lt (<) at ../newscript4.pl line 17, <$HMP> line 2225. (<-- is the last line of the hmp file). to me, it looks like the script wants to continue even after the last line of the hmp file? but I don't know where the error is. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: yes that is true. but still the script just won't stop running (the warning just repeats infinite amount of times) and i have to force stop it with ctrl+c. if I turn off "use warnings;", I dont get any output. and even the output if warnings; is on is not complete: the script cannot find the last few lines it is supposed to find (tried that with several datasets).

Comment: @Prawn: Again, can you provide the shortest example of the data demonstrating the behaviour?

Comment: I think I meanwhile found a solution myself. I extended the inner while condition to while ($pos_h < $pos_a and !eof $HMP) {... now no warnings are returned and the script finds the correct amount of lines! I'm sorry if I have wasted your time, I am completely new to this, so I hope you forgive me if I am a little overzealous sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to put this in an answer, since I can't put code into a comment =)

Okay I just created this mini-dataset in which I searched two lines that match each other in both files via less:

alleles.txt:

```
rs#     alleles chrom   pos     strand  assembly#       center  protLSID        assayLSID       panelLSID       QCcode  M.10    M.101   M.103
NA      NA      1       10971981        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      2       1       2
NA      NA      1       11716572        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      1       1       1
```

hmp.txt:

```
chr     pse.bp  bp      nalleles        maf     bur-0   can-0   col-0   ct-1    edi-0   hi-0    kn-0    ler-0   mt-0    no-0    oy-0    po-0    rsch-4  sf-2    ts
1       11230382        10971981        3       14      GGTA    GGTA    GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GGTA    GG      0
1       12050466        11716572        2       15      A       A       A       A       A       T       A       A       T       A       A       A       T       T
```

both lines match each other in the required fields, right? However, if I run the script you gave me, it only returns:

```
1       11230382        10971981        3       14      GGTA    GGTA    GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GG      GGTA    GG      0
```

which is only the first line.
Just to make sure that this is not the reason, I should mention that hmp.txt contains way more columns at the end than M.10, M.101, M.103. I just included the first three because the actual file contains about 1000 of these columns.
By the way, is there a way to also return the header line? I know I could write it manually since it is not that much of text, but just for the heck of it...

thanks again for your help!

Prawn

Comment: @choroba forgot to flag this... ;)

Comment: @choroba: I also tried out something else. I thought maybe $chr_h and $pos_h must be reset for every repition of the outer while loop, so I put "my (chr_h, pos_h) = (-1, -1);" into the outer while loop. Funny thing is: for the mini-example above it works (returns both lines), for the original files it doesn't, though! maybe thats because there are lines that do not match in the original files...?